# Geocoding - get lat/long for 110,000 address

Tags: apex, api, webservices, google-map, geocoding

What I have:

- List of 110,000 address (street + city+ state+ zip code)
- all address are from US

What I am looking for:

- get "geocodes" (latitude/longitude) of all address.
- using a opensource API, or a service of a website

In my research I have found some API and websites. But I am not sure if they suit my requirements

- Google Maps API

  - It was a limit if 2500 requests per IP per day.
- openstreetmap

  - Lat/long not updated for all records.

Can any one suggest me if any other possibilities exists.

Thanks,

Comment: Can't you jut open street map the ones that work, and use google maps API for the rest? Is the google maps API a hard limit, or are you required to pay for additional. Maybe best to just pay, if that is an option.

Answer (score 1):

If its a one time activity, I suggest using the following service: http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/batch-geocode/#.Vlbun8aBgqj

I had used it once and it gave good results. I am not sure if there is a limit to the number of records it can process in one go but I was able to work with a large set of records though not large as your one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there any API for this to get lat and long.

Comment: There is no API as far as I know. This would work if its an one time activity. You can export the details from Salesforce (if its already in there), upload the CSV to the side and it would return back a CSV. Use that to update the records back in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I am using Geolocation but we pay money for Google.For your case, if it fix 110 000 address, you can do some sort of batch job to get the lat/long and store it in the custom object.You can call the API 2500 perday  mean in 44 days, you will get all the la/long.After that, just get the data from the object.

I am not sure this is  work, but it might just give you an idea.